# Android webview doesn't load homepage but load all other pages

Tags: android, webview

Android webview doesn't load homepage but load all other pages! the weird thing is that when I click on Home from the original site menu in the app it load homepage correctly without any problems but if I try to click on it from the top navigation menu it doesn't load at all!

```
package com.example.couponcheetah;

import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebViewController extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        view.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        // hide element by id
        view.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                "document.getElementById('site-navigation').style.display='none';})()");
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and here's homefragment:

```
package com.example.couponcheetah.ui.home;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;

import com.example.couponcheetah.WebViewController;
import com.example.couponcheetah.R;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        WebView webView=root.findViewById(R.id.web_view_home);
        webView.loadUrl("https://couponcheetah.com");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewController());
        return root;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your problem right
try put your code in onstart not oncreateView as

```html
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;
     private WebView webView;
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        webView=root.findViewById(R.id.web_view_home);
        return root;
    }
    
    // impelment funcation onStart and put your code{
    webView.loadUrl("https://couponcheetah.com");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewController());
    }
}
```